# Does the history of the universe change when the initial conditions change in superdeterministic theories?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-interpretations

In quantum mechanics, [superdeterminism](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.01324) is a loophole in Bell's theorem, that allows one to evade it by postulating that all systems being measured are causally correlated with the choices of which measurements to make on them. In other words, according to this model, absolutely everything in the Universe, every event was predetermined by the initial conditions during the Big Bang. Do I understand correctly that if the initial conditions were slightly different, the history of the Universe would be completely different?

Comment: Too weak on QM to post an answer, but papers by Hossenfelder are always good.